# Android TV Application

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an android application for phones and tablets. Now I want to create suitable TV application of my app with leanback support library widgets and I read different tutorials for TV apps. 
Now I want to know if I should add new package for tv to my current project or create new project and release different apk for tv? which one is better? does adding package to my current project have effects on apk size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android TV best practice](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-tv.html) :

> In most cases, we recommend delivering your TV experience as part of
>   your existing app for phones, tablets, and other devices, using the
>   same package name and store listing. This approach lets users upgrade
>   to your TV experience seamlessly and also lets you take advantage of
>   the reviews and ratings you’ve earned in your app for phones and
>   tablets.

You can use a single apk :

> You can bundle your TV intents, leanback library, and TV-specific code
>   and resources as part of a single APK solution for all supported
>   devices

Or you can use multiple apk support :

> If necessary, you can use [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) to deliver a
>   custom binary to Android TV devices under the same package name and
>   store listing that you use for phones and tablets.

Comment: I agree that a single apk is best, you can just have a different launcher activity for leanback.

Comment: This may be old but please help me clear this thought, but if I put all apps in 1 apk (that includes phone, tablet and TV) will it be more larger in size, which I believe is a bad deal, any thought ?